# Making a key become a value in PairRDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
Spark 2.0.1
```

I have two classes:

```
public class Key{
    private Object[] values;
    //a couple of other fields

    public Object[] getKeyFields(){
        return values;
    }
}

public class Value{
    private Object[] values;
    //a couple of other fields

    public Object[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

Now I want to do some operations with this fields.

I.

```
JavaSparcContext sc = //
JavaPairRDD<Key, Value> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(...);
JavaPairRDD<Key, Object[]> rddArr = rddArr.mapValues(Value::getValues);
JavaPairRDD<String, Object[]> stringKeyRdd = rddArr.mapToPair(p -> {
    return new Tuple2<>(p._1.toString(), p._2)
});
stringKeyRdd.sortByKey()
    .saveAsHadoopFile(...);
```

And it works pretty much fine with a good performance. Here is the result:[image]

II. 
But if I try to make `Key`-array to become a value in my `JavaPairRDD` I got performance degradation.

```
JavaSparcContext sc = //
JavaPairRDD<Key, Value> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(...);
JavaPairRDD<Key, Object[]> rddArr = rddArr.mapValues(Value::getValues);
JavaPairRDD<String, Object[]> stringKeyRdd = rddArr.mapToPair(p -> {
    return new Tuple2<>(p._1.toString(), p._1.getKeyFields()) // <--- Now keys
});
stringKeyRdd.sortByKey()
    .saveAsHadoopFile(...);
```

The result:

[image]

***QUESTION:*** Why does Shuffle Read and Shuffle Write increased in that case almost twice?

Comment: Have you tried running each example a couple of times to check you always get the same result ?